# opencv align two images by keypoints

Tags: python, opencv

I have two images

image1(dog): [Download link](https://pixabay.com/de/images/download/akita-5964180_640.jpg?attachment)

image2 (bird):

[image]

I want to align image2 on image1 by keypoints. So the goal that both keypoints overlaps and the bird image is resized and scaled on top of the dog image.

Image 1 with keypoints:
[image]

Image two with keypoints:

[image]

This are my keypoints (csv file). The coordinates are x and y in the original image (download links at top):

```
bird_x,bird_y,dog_x,dog_y
0,43,265,48
88,12,297,29
172,1,332,23
211,17,349,32
283,60,378,60
143,109,321,98
```

How can I do this with opencv and python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick rough way to do it is by resizing the smaller image to the bounding box formed by the keypoints of the bigger image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_dog = cv2.imread("akita.jpg")
img_bird = cv2.imread("gull.png")

#Reconstruct the keypoints
bird_keypoints = ((0,43), (88,12), (172,1), (211,17), (283,60), (143,109))
dog_keypoints = ((265,48), (297,29), (332,23), (349,32), (378,60), (321, 98))

#New dimension of the smaller image - calculate keypoints max x and y range
min_x = min([p[0] for p in dog_keypoints])
max_x = max([p[0] for p in dog_keypoints])
min_y = min([p[1] for p in dog_keypoints])
max_y = max([p[1] for p in dog_keypoints])

scale_height = max_y - min_y
scale_width = max_x - min_x
center = (0.5*(min_x + max_x), 0.5*(min_y + max_y))

#resize smaller image
img_bird_scaled = cv2.resize(img_bird, (scale_width,scale_height), 
                             interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


#overwrite part of the dog image with the new scaled smaller image
img_dog[min_y:max_y, min_x:max_x] = img_bird_scaled

cv2.imshow("test", img_dog)
```

If you need to paste only the bird without the background, you will have to deal with the alpha channel.

[image: Result image]

Comment: thank you :) I started a new question because that is not what I really want. But it is my fault not be clear enough so I opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812111/opencv-align-two-images-by-keypoints-with-stretching